# Iterating through the same key in different items python dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

i have a complex dictionary that looks like this.

```
{"Div 4 A Herrar": {
    "0": {"convertedTime": "86", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "SKIF Semberija", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Floda BoIF", "time": "00:00", "events": []}, 
    "1": {"convertedTime": "40", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Partille IF FK ", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Kode IF", "time": "01:00", "events": []}, 
    "2": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "IK Kongah\u00e4lla", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Romelanda UF", "time": "02:00", "events": []}, 
    "3": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "IK Virgo", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "United Africa FC", "time": "03:00", "events": []}, 
    "4": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Hisingsbacka FC", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Guldhedens IK", "time": "04:00", "events": []}, 
    "5": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "IF Warta", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Bergums IF", "time": "05:00", "events": []}
    }
 "Div 5 A Herrar": {
    "0": {"convertedTime": "86", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "SKIF Semberija", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Floda BoIF", "time": "00:00", "events": []}, 
    "1": {"convertedTime": "40", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Partille IF FK ", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Kode IF", "time": "01:00", "events": []}, 
    "2": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "IK Kongah\u00e4lla", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Romelanda UF", "time": "02:00", "events": []}, 
    "3": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "IK Virgo", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "United Africa FC", "time": "03:00", "events": []}, 
    "4": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Hisingsbacka FC", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Guldhedens IK", "time": "04:00", "events": []}, 
    "5": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "IF Warta", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Bergums IF", "time": "05:00", "events": []}
    }
}
```

There are a few more items but its not relevant since you get the structure of the dictionary.

Now what i need to do is to iterate through all the **time** keys in this dictionary because i will need to change the value of them. Meaning it will have to iterate through 6 time key/pair values from "Div 4 A Herrar" and 6 from "Div 5 A Herrar". How on earth can i accomplish anything like that I'm totally lost

Comment: To be clear: you need to visit all of the `convertedTime` keys for each of the dictionaries in the overall dictionary.  Do you know how to visit all of the `convertedTime` keys in one of those dictionaries?  Would you know how to visit each of those dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to the time value:

```
for key1 in dict:
    for key2 in dict[key1]:
       dict[key1][key2]['time'] = 'newTime'
```

Comment: Wonderufl, i didn't know i could just write key1 and it would automatically know that. Thanks!! u made life ez for me

Comment: when you iterate through dicts you always get the keyvalues, in advance, when you iterate `for key, value in dict` you get both the key an the value item.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure you presented maintains, you can use one of these 2 methods. Otherwise, you would have to make a recursive function.

```
dict_of_herrars = {
    #...
}
```

### Method1

```
# herrar = "Div 4 A Herrar", etc
for herrar, herrar_dict in dict_of_herrars.items():
    # game = "0","1",etc
    for game, game_dict in herrar_dict.items():
        game_dict["time"]="13:37"
```

### Method2

```
def iter_time(dict_of_herrars):
    # herrar = "Div 4 A Herrar", etc
    for herrar, herrar_dict in dict_of_herrars.items():
        # game = "0","1",etc
        for game, game_dict in herrar_dict.items():
            def change_time(new_time,game_dict=game_dict):
                game_dict["time"]=newtime
            yield change_time

for change_time in iter_time(dict_of_herrars):
    change_time("13:37")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Demo on [repl.it](http://repl.it/2l3/1)

#### Code:

```
d = {"Div 4 A Herrar" : {
    "0": {"convertedTime": "86", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "SKIF Semberija", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Floda BoIF", "time": "00:00", "events": []}, 
    "1": {"convertedTime": "40", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Partille IF FK ", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Kode IF", "time": "01:00", "events": []}, 
    "2": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "IK Kongah\\u00e4lla", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Romelanda UF", "time": "02:00", "events": []}, 
    "3": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "IK Virgo", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "United Africa FC", "time": "03:00", "events": []}, 
    "4": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Hisingsbacka FC", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Guldhedens IK", "time": "04:00", "events": []}, 
    "5": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "IF Warta", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Bergums IF", "time": "05:00", "events": []}
    },
 "Div 5 A Herrar" : {
    "0": {"convertedTime": "86", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "SKIF Semberija", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Floda BoIF", "time": "00:00", "events": []}, 
    "1": {"convertedTime": "40", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Partille IF FK ", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Kode IF", "time": "01:00", "events": []}, 
    "2": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "IK Kongah\\u00e4lla", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Romelanda UF", "time": "02:00", "events": []}, 
    "3": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "IK Virgo", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "United Africa FC", "time": "03:00", "events": []}, 
    "4": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "Hisingsbacka FC", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Guldhedens IK", "time": "04:00", "events": []}, 
    "5": {"convertedTime": "", "awayScore": "0", "homeTeam": "IF Warta", "homeScore": "0", "awayTeam": "Bergums IF", "time": "05:00", "events": []}
    }
}

for i in d:
    for j in d[i]:
        for k in d[i][j]:
            if k == "time":
                print "Original Time: ", d[i][j][k]
                d[i][j][k] = "something"
                print "Changed to: ", d[i][j][k]
```

#### Output:

```
Original Time:  01:00
Changed to:  something
Original Time:  00:00
Changed to:  something
Original Time:  03:00
Changed to:  something
Original Time:  02:00
Changed to:  something
Original Time:  05:00
Changed to:  something
Original Time:  04:00
Changed to:  something
Original Time:  01:00
Changed to:  something
Original Time:  00:00
Changed to:  something
Original Time:  03:00
Changed to:  something
Original Time:  02:00
Changed to:  something
Original Time:  05:00
Changed to:  something
Original Time:  04:00
Changed to:  something
```